# Bash: Using asterisk in any bash command in home directory exits with error "Unrecognized options --list-sessions"

Tags: bash, session, tmux

Title.
This same/similar error seems to occur with any command in bash if I:

1. Am in my home directory, i.e. after `cd ~`. It doesnt occur in other places.
2. Have an asterisk/wildcard in the command matching all of the files+dirs. It doesnt happen without the asterisk as far as I can tell.

Examples:

```
me@mypc:~$ ls *
ls: unrecognized option '--list-sessions'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
me@mypc:~$ ls
...
Desktop
Downloads
...
(prints all directories)
me@mypc:~$ ls ./*
(prints all subdirectory subdirectories)
me@mypc:~$ ls .*
...
.vscode:
argv.json  extensions

.wine:
dosdevices  drive_c  system.reg  userdef.reg  user.reg
...
(prints all subdirectories with their contents)

me@mypc:~$ du -sch *
du: unrecognized option '--list-sessions'
Try 'du --help' for more information.
me@mypc:~$ du -sch .*
du: cannot read directory './.dbus': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory './.pgadmin': Permission denied
66G .
du: cannot read directory '../postgres/.gnupg': Permission denied
64K ..
66G total

me@mypc:~$ grep "\-\-list-sessions" *
grep: unrecognized option '--list-sessions'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

And so on.
The list-sessions flag seems reminiscent of this tmux command:

```
me@mypc:~$ tmux list-sessions
error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1000/default (No such file or directory)
me@mypc:~$ whereis tmux
tmux: /usr/bin/tmux /usr/share/man/man1/tmux.1.gz
```

The list-sessions error in other commands persists with and without running tmux server.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a file in your home directory named `--list-sessions` and the `*`, when expanded, is causing your command (eg, `ls`, `du`) to treat the file name as an option:

Consider ...

```
$ mkdir /tmp/ttt
$ cd /tmp/ttt
$ touch -- '--list-sessions'
$ ls -a
--list-sessions  ./  ../

$ ls *
dir: unknown option -- list-sessions
Try 'dir --help' for more information.
$ ls -- *                               # disable further command line option processing
--list-sessions

$ du -k *
du: unknown option -- list-sessions
Try 'du --help' for more information.
$ du -k -- *                            # disable further command line option processing
0       --list-sessions
```

**NOTE**: The `--` used in the above commands disables further command line option processing, eg, [What does double dash mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)